# Using checkboxes to filter data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a MySQL database that using PHP, churns out the following HTML.

```
<div class="item filterable united-states" data-amount="14000">
    Supplier Country: United States
    Delivery Estimation: 5 days
    Quote Amount: 14000
<div>

<div class="item filterable united-states" data-amount="7000">
    Supplier Country: United States
    Delivery Estimation: 30 days
    Quote Amount: 7000
<div>

<div class="item filterable united-kingdom" data-amount="13000">
    Supplier Country: United Kingdom
    Delivery Estimation: 15 days
    Quote Amount: 13000
<div>

<div class="item filterable germany" data-amount="8700">
    Supplier Country: Germany
    Delivery Estimation: 22 days
    Quote Amount: 8700
<div>
```

I have also created a loop that creates checkboxes based on the countries in the result set.
The HTML for that looks like:

```
<div class="checkbox check-default" id="country-filter">
    <strong>Countries</strong><br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="germany" id="germany-checkbox" />
    <label for="germany-checkbox">Germany</label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="united-kingdom" id="united-kingdom-checkbox" />
    <label for="united-kingdom-checkbox">United Kingdom</label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="united-states" id="united-states-checkbox" />
    <label for="united-states-checkbox">United States</label>
</div>
```

So I found some jQuery snippet and edited it to filter the results like this:

```
$("#country-filter :checkbox").click(function() {
$("div.item").hide();
$("#country-filter :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
$("div." + $(this).val()).show().slideDown(400);
});
});
```

The jQuery snippet helps to filter the results but not in the way I want it to. The results load just fine and when a checkbox is checked, it gets the results that should be displayed just fine. But when all checkboxes are unchecked all results disappear until a checkbox is clicked.

Also, I want another filter to handle the amount portion working in tandem with the country filter.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, replace your `$("div.item").hide();` with

```
if ($("#country-filter :checkbox:checked").length > 0)
{
    $("div.item").hide();
}
else
{
    $("div.item").show();
}
```

for the other, set up a variable (javascript or jquery) and set it to 0 before you go into your each loop.  Grab and add the contents of the data-amount param from each of the divs you show.  Once you're done, you'll have a variable with the total in it

Comment: it still did not solve the problem. When no checkbox is selected, all the results vanish.

Comment: my error.  Forgot to include the ":checked".  Try this version.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Do you have any ideas as to how to go about the other one?

Comment: I told you how to do it.  just look up at the answer and start reading from "for the other".